# for loop - .split and int

Tags: python

I wrote 2 funcs that work good, but I want to change part of my code to make it more efficient, using for loop with "jump" of every 8 charts.
when I run `verify_checksum`, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

but when I run it with lines remarks with `#` it works fine.
any idea how fix it without change other parts of the code? (there are more funcs that works with these, and its cause a mess).

my code:

```
def xor_bytes(byte1, byte2):
    byte1, byte2=byte1.split(), byte2.split()
    xor=""
    a=0
    for i in byte1:
        for j in i:
            t=int(byte2[0][a])^int(j)
            xor+="".join(str(t))
            a+=1
    return xor


def verify_checksum(datagram):
    datagram=list(datagram)
    org_checksum=datagram[48:56]
    org_checksum="".join(org_checksum)
    x=48
    for i in datagram[48:56]:
        datagram[x]='0'
        x+=1
    datagram="".join(datagram)

    res=xor_bytes(datagram[0:8], datagram[8:16])
    for i in (16,88,8):
        res=xor_bytes(res, i)
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[16:24])
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[24:32])
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[32:40])
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[40:48])
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[48:56])
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[56:64])
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[64:72])
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[72:80])
    #res=xor_bytes(res,datagram[80:88])

    if res==org_checksum:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

input:

```
verify_checksum("1111000000001111000011111111000001010101101010101010111001110011001000000110101101101001")
```

output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lines that are commented out, you're passing two strings as parameters.

In the loop, you're passing a string and an int as parameters.

The error is on the byte2.split() since it's an int.  Pass in a section of the datagram, not a numeric position and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `for` loop like this:

```
for i in (16,88,8):
    res=xor_bytes(res, i)
```

You then try to call `.split` on `i` (which is an integer) in the `xor_bytes` function:

```
byte1, byte2=byte1.split(), byte2.split()
```

(`i` gets passed in as `byte2`).

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish here, so I can't help you fix the problem, but that's why it is happening.

---

Perhaps you wanted something like:

```
bytes_range = range(16,89,8)  #make 89 the upper bound so that 88 is included in the range
for start,end in zip(bytes_range[:-1],bytes_range[1:]):
    res = xor_bytes(res,datagram[start:end])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop doesn't look ***anything*** like the commented lines.

```
for i in range(16,88,8):
    res=xor_bytes(res, datagram[i:i + 8])
```

Comment: Your fix is a little nicer than mine.  +1.